# How to intuitively understand the power set of $\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that power set of $\{a\}$ is $\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$. Similarly, I tried reasoning the fact that power set of $\{\emptyset\}$ should be $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, but this doesn't give me any intuitive sense.

Can someone help me to understand what exactly does it mean?

Comment: You are thinking $\emptyset = \{ a \}$, but this is wrong, since this would mean that $a$ is an element of the emptyset.

Comment: Power set of $\{\emptyset\}$ is, indeed, $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$. But, the set $\{\emptyset\}$ is not empty.

Comment: The empty set is $\emptyset$.  The power set of the empty set is not the powerset of $\{\emptyset\}$, which is a set containing the empty set.

Comment: @amWhy: The power set of the empty set is $\{\emptyset\}$, which is a set containing the empty set. ;-)

Comment: @tomasz,  Please reread my comment from yesterday.  I said "The **power set** of the $\emptyset$ is not the **power set** of $\{\emptyset\}$.  This is in response to the two distinct questions, one asked in the title (about the power set of $\emptyset$, and one asked in the body of the post, about the  "... power set of {∅}".  Never did I deny that the power set of $\emptyset$ is $\{\emptyset\}$. Please read others' comments more carefully.

Comment: Note the first sentence in the accepted answer, @tomasz.  That's the same thing I noted in my comment, accept that instead of saying "the power set of the set that only contains $\emptyset$, I wrote, "the power set of $\{\emptyset\}$, which, if I'm not mistaken, is precisely "the power set of the set that only contains $\emptyset$"

Comment: @amWhy: It was a joke. The core of which was the ambiguity of the English language. Nevermind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be careful, the power set of $\emptyset$ is not the same as the power set of the set that only contains $\emptyset$.

The power set of $\emptyset$ is the set that contains all the subsets of the empty set, and the only possible subset of the empty set is itself, so $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$. But, the power set of $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set that contains all the subsets of $\{\emptyset\}$, and those are both the empty set and the set that contains the empty set. Therefore, $\mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\})=\{\emptyset\,, \{\emptyset\}\}$.

I hope I didn't confuse you too much.

Answer (score 5):

In the title you ask about the powerset of the null set. Since the null set is $\emptyset$, the title thus asks for $P(\emptyset)$.

But in the body of your question you are asking about $P(\{ \emptyset \})$, which is something different. Indeed, $\{ \emptyset \}$ is not the null set, but is the set that contains the null set as its only element.

Maybe you didn't realize that $\emptyset \not = \{ \emptyset \}$?

Comment: This is probably a good argument for *not using* $\emptyset$ when teaching beginning set theory and instead using $\{\}$. It's considerably harder to mix up $\{\{\}\}$ with $\{\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Power set of a null set consists of only one element: Null set. Since null set is subset of every set. But your interpretation is not correct, {∅} is not null.